# Call React Native App to receive shared info from Browser

Tags: ios, react-native, sharing

If you have used Pinterest, you know that from Safari or Chrome if you tap the share button, the pinterest will show up in the sharing options

[image]

Then if you tap the pinterest icon, the app will pops up as modal so you can select image and board to save to

[image]

My question is: can we do that in React Native? I mean I want my app shows up in sharing option and can receive data from it.

Comment: have you find a solution?

Comment: @PewhGosh Check this out this https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension. It's quite complicated but worth a try. I was not able to complete this feature of my project, because it's frozen. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm yet to implement this myself, I'm interested in having my React-Native project both receive and share data, to and from other apps. Below are some links to projects and articles that seem to do this:

### Receive from other apps

https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension

https://codeburst.io/building-a-mobile-share-extension-for-a-react-native-app-bff4ef91d44f

https://github.com/meedan/react-native-share-menu <- Add the app as a receiver (unmaintained code, May 2018)

### Share to other apps

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html <- Official send API for data to other apps

https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share
 <- Share Social , Sending Simple Data to Other Apps